# Retrieve Access Control List of Documents for Specific User on Google Docs?

Tags: acl, google-docs

I have a large website at www.mydomain.com.  There are 1000 new documents per month and 100 new users per week lets say.  I need to be able to programmatically do the following:

- user goes to www.mydomain.com/documents
- user sees list of all documents they have access to (not ALL of the docs)

I know you can [retrieve an ACL for each document individually](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#AccessControlLists).  But is there a way to retrieve an ACL for each "user", a list of all the documents they have access to, in one HTTP request?  Something like this, but for Docs (and not just for document "owners"):

[Retrieving only calendars that a user owns](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#RetrievingOwnCalendars).

I'd love to know, because it seems like I'd have to parse 10,000 document "entry" tags, find the ACL, see if user is in ACL...  That seems crazy.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the API can provide you [the desired list](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/reference.html#Parameters) by reader or writer.